# Intermediate Values and Thread Safety

Tags: c++, thread-safety

In a expression like:

```
a = b + c;
```

Is it possible that the compiler optimizes the code above to do:

```
a = b;
a += c;
```

What I really want to know is if other threads can see the result of a intermediate computation in the variable at lefthand side of `=`.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know, but I highly doubt it.

Comment: Is this about C++11? Are there any atomic variables involved?

Comment: On common architectures, there's no add instruction that targets memory; it has to go through a register, and then have the result moved back to memory, so I don't see any reason for the compiler to ever do this. I'm not sure about the standard's guarantees, though.

Comment: @dyp No atomic variables.

Comment: @dauphic This was just an example. In more complex expressions, can the compiler use the variable at lefthand side of = to store intermediate values?

Comment: The assignment is sequenced after the value computation of the left and right expression. **But** if the access from another thread is not sequenced wrt to the modification (happens before), you'll get undefined behaviour.

Comment: [intro.multithread]/4 "Two expression evaluations *conflict* if one of them modifies a memory location and the other one
accesses or modifies the same memory location." and /21 "The execution of a program contains a *data race* if it contains two conflicting actions in different threads,
at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other. Any such data race results in
undefined behavior."

Comment: Ignoring the standard and looking at implementations in the wild, you should at least expect problems when `a` is be a user-defined or otherwise larger-than-wordsized type. Then the copy (or even move) from the intermediate to `a` wouldn't be atomic, even if the intermediate calculation isn't visible to other threads.

Comment: In the second part of [this talk by Herb Sutter](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-2-of-2), he explains how compilers could generate code that would produce more writes than intended. But also how those would be illegal in a multi-threaded environment. I think its about 15 minutes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the as-if rule, an optimizing compiler can do (nearly) anything it likes with expressions that don't involve atomics since there's no way another thread could observe the difference in a data-race-free program. So yes the compiler could do that, and other threads could only see the intermediate result via a data race.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have access to the standard right now, but according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order:

> 8) The side effect (modification of the left argument) of the built-in
>   assignment operator and of all built-in compound assignment operators
>   is sequenced after the value computation (but not the side effects) of
>   both left and right arguments, and is sequenced before the value
>   computation of the assignment expression (that is, before returning
>   the reference to the modified object)

What this seems to be saying is that the modification of `a` is sequenced after the evaluation of `b + c`, so the compiler cannot modify `a` in two steps.

This doesn't prevent the optimizer from doing whatever it pleases, but I can't see any reason that it would write to `a` twice.